# Anaconda and Canopy together

Tags: python, anaconda, canopy

I installed Enthought Canopy as part of a course I am doing. Then as part of another course, I installed Anaconda. I'm going through the instructions to create environments in the Anaconda, and when I try to come out of an environment I just created it seems to be coming out of the Anaconda environment/shell altogether. Also, when I try to run any command, it seems to be switching to the Canopy shell (in Anaconda Prompt).

Below is what is happening in the Anaconda Prompt:

```
(C:\Users\SasiKanth\Anaconda3) C:\Users\SasiKanth>activate ucity

(ucity) C:\Users\SasiKanth>deactivate

C:\Users\SasiKanth>conda
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\SasiKanth>conda list
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\SasiKanth>activate Anaconda3
(Canopy 64bit) C:\Users\SasiKanth>activate ucity
(Canopy 64bit) C:\Users\SasiKanth>
```

Below are my queries:
Is there any problem in having two different python softwares/environments installed in the same system?
If yes, are there any measures I need to take to handle multiple environments?
How can I switch between Anaconda and Canopy shells/environments (if we can)?

Comment: Uh, are you *also* using virtual environments?

Comment: I can't answer the questions but this seems a bit of a mess. I'm not sure what kind of tasks would mandate having both installed; are you able to narrow it down to 1? There is nothing I could do in Canopy that I can't do through Anaconda/Spyder.

Comment: What version of Canopy is installed? Multiple Python installations can co-exist on a system, but it is important to keep them isolated (none should be set as default or referenced in any environment variable, notably PATH and PYTHONPATH). Canopy does not need any changes in PATH to run, so should not interfere with Anaconda in any way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I'm new to python...in multiple places I read that it was a good practice to use virtual environments to keep modules isolated, and hence using them :)

Comment: @roganjosh, I installed them as part of different courses I have taken up. I understand that having one IDE should be sufficient in the long run, but for now I want to continue with both of them until my courses, and then would like to stick to one of them based on my experience.

Comment: @JonathanMarch, the Enthought Canopy (1.7.4.3348) installed a version Python 2.7.11 and with the Anaconda, I installed Python 3.6.3 - both were requirements of the different courses...and after Canopy installation, I see that the Windows Path variable seem to be updated with the Canopy\User and Canopy\User\Scripts - should I remove them as per your suggestion. What would I miss if do so?

Comment: But are you using a `virtualenv` environment? `conda` acts as a *replacement* for `virtualenv`

Comment: Yes, remove Canopy from PATH. It's not needed; indeed, in the current Canopy release (2.1.3, with 2.1.6 due within the week), it's never set. See https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204470190-Windows-editing-the-PATH-environment-variable-for-Python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not using the 'virtualenv' package, but the 'conda create' to create the virtual environments...it is when I'm trying to deactivate the virtual env within the conda, I'm coming out completely out of the Anaconda shell...this is the main doubt I have - why is it coming out of the Anaconda shell altogether? (a workaround I found for now to get back into the Anaconda shell is to activate the root shell after going into the Anaconda/Scripts path)

Comment: @JonathanMarch, thanks for the tip. Is there anywhere that I can upgrade the Canopy version in place (without uninstalling)? And further to my above query - does having the PATH reference to Canopy cause the 'deactivate' command in conda env to come out of the Anaconda shell itself?

Comment: What is the Anaconda shell? What is the Canopy shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anywhere that I can upgrade the Canopy version in place (without uninstalling)?

In brief, no. V1.x uses virtual envs. V2.x uses flat envs. See [Updating from Canopy v1 to Canopy v2](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001673423-Updating-from-Canopy-v1-to-Canopy-v2)